# Mongoose query fails if I chain .sort()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, coffeescript

Using Mongoose 4.3.6

This query works perfectly : (This is coffeeScript, I have added the Javascript equivalent below)

```
age = 43200000 # Milliseconds = 24h

Ad
    .find
        site : body.codeName
        checked :
            $lt : new Date( (new Date()) - age )
    .exec (err,ads) ->
        return res.status(500).send err if err
        log "Found #{ads.length} ads"
```

So it works, and I get

> "Found 38246 ads"

But if I want to sort on the "checked" field :

```
age = 43200000 # Milliseconds = 24h

Ad
        .find
            site : body.codeName
            checked :
                $lt : new Date( (new Date()) - age )
        .sort '-checked'
        .exec (err,ads) ->
            return res.status(500).send err if err
            log "Found #{ads.length} ads" # ads is undefined
```

Then I get

> "Error : ads is undefined"

Obviously the "checked" field exists, since query #1 works. It's of type "Date" in my Mongoose model.

---

Same code as compiled Javascript :

```
var age = 43200000;

Ad.find({
  site: body.codeName,
  checked: {
    $lt: new Date((new Date()) - age)
  }
}).exec(function(err, ads) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
  return log("Found " + ads.length + " ads");
});
```

> "Found 38246 ads"

```
var age = 43200000;

Ad.find({
      site: body.codeName,
      checked: {
        $lt: new Date((new Date()) - age)
      }
}).sort('-checked').exec(function(err, ads) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
      return log("Found " + ads.length + " ads"); // Error : ads is undefined
});
```

> "Error : ads is undefined"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried the other variations for sort, i.e. use values of 1, `desc`, or `descending`?

Comment: Yes I have tried `.sort({checked:-1})` and other variations from the documentation, no luck.

Comment: What about this variation `Ad.find({...}, null, {sort: '-checked'}, function(err, ads) { ... });` or `Ad.find({...}, null, {sort: {checked: -1}}, function(err, ads) { ... });`?

Comment: No, it didn't work, but by enabling Mongoose debugging I managed to get the following error output : `[MongoError: getMore executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554893 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes]` It looks like MongoDB can't sort if the query returns too many results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling Mongoose debugging, I managed to get the following error output :

> [MongoError: getMore executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data
>   usage of 33554893 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes]

It looks like MongoDB just can't sort if the query returns too many results...